# How to save file using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to save file by sending `FormData` by ajax to controller, problem is that my ajax is not working even when I use `FormData` function to get all variables into one form.

I have tried to use form, but in table, I could not use form tags, because my button is in another td. When I use it for whole table, it is not working too, I created `FormData` where I appended all my variables, rest of them are working, but image is not.

index.cshtml:

```
<tr class="form" style="display:none">

    <td class="name">
        <input type="text" name="Jméno" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="price">
        <input type="number" name="Cena" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="quantity">
        <input type="number" name="Mnozstvi" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="image">
        <input type="file" id="fileOne" name="fileOne" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="FirstSave" type="button" id="btnUpload">Uložit</button>

        <button class="getBack">Zahodit</button>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(".FirstSave").click(function () {

      let file = document.getElementById('fileOne').file;
      let form = new FormData;

      form.append('Image', file);
      form.append('Name', name);
      form.append('Price', price);
      form.append('Quantity', quantity);
      $.ajax({
         url: "Insert",
         method: "POST",
         cache: false,
         processData: false,
         data: form,
    });
})
```

Products getter and setter

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

}
```

Products Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(Product product)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = product.Image;
    if (file != null)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        product.ImageUrl = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Products/"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(product.ImageUrl);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead:

```
var fileName = file.FileName;
```

replace your line

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

so if i were to change your code:

```
    var fileName = file.FileName;
    product.ImageUrl = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(product.ImageUrl);
```

if this isnt enough then check this js code that I am using for one of my uploads:

```
for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that is working for me:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myFormId", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      var formData = new FormData(this);

      $.ajax({
           url: 'my url',
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           success: function (response) {
               if (response) {
                   // Do whatever you want to do with response 
               }
           },
           error: function (error) {
               console.log(error)
           },
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false
      });
      return false;
 });
```

I see you are missing `contentType: false` in your ajax settings. This is required for uploading file with ajax.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have added into code contentType:false but image is still not saving into file.

Comment: @Michael Have your confirmed that your form tag containing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

- first confirmed that your form tag containing form
  enctype="multipart/form-data".
  second add contentType: false in your ajax call

  $.ajax({
  url: form_url,
  type:form_method,
  contentType: false,
  data: formData, });